# Why can't I hide the status bar?

Tags: ios, swift

I use the following line of code to hide the status bar:

`view.window?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar`

What is surprising me is that this line of code does not work from within any of the "life cycle" methods of the `view`: `viewDidLoad()`, `viewWillAppear(:)`. However, when I create a button and hook it up to an action method the code above works perfectly and hides the status bar behind the window. I want to be able to call `view.window?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar` in `viewDidLoad()`. Can anyone please help me understand why it does not work from within the mentioned `view` "life cycle" methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither in `viewDidLoad` nor `viewWillAppear` the view controller is in the view hierarchy, therefore `view.window` is `nil`.

You might work around that by using `viewDidAppear` or access the window using `UIApplication.shared.delegate.window` instead.

In general it's not a good idea to change the `level` of the main window though.

Comment: How should I hide the status bar on a modally presented view controller if changing the window `level` is bad practice?

Comment: @A.Jam You can make the controller to hide the statusbar, or create a new window and show the controller/view in it.

Comment: How do you make a view controller hide the status bar? Is there a built in method because I did some research couldn't find anything...

Comment: @A.Jam https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621440-prefersstatusbarhidden

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your ViewController will only be able to adjust the status bar if you set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to YES in your info.plist. Otherwise it is set by global parameters in your plist or proj file.

Comment: I am not trying to adjust the status bar. I am trying to set the app window at the same level as the status bar. I also changed `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES` nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you only wanted to hide status bar use:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES]
```